# Build client-server system which not base on webservice

Tags: client-server

I must build client-server system (ERP) run on LAN.
My server app have some functions X,Y,Z. Each function get data on server --> process --> return result.

How to allow client **connect securely to server and call functions X, Y, Z then receive results?** *(I don't want to use web-service technique)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write your server program to read input from stdin and write output to stdout.
2. Then install a SSH server on your server computer. Configure SSH so the users are only allowed to start your server program.
3. Give all users access via SSH-keypairs.

This gives you encrpytion and user authentification. This allows you to write a server that handles several processes in parallel.